# With what can I replace a MLCC capacitor to ground of 6.3V and 4.7uf

Tags: capacitor, grounding, ethernet, motherboard, mlcc

[image: schematic of the circuit where the cap broke off]

I have a mobo and the cap highlighted above in the picture **C4** (**6,3V 4,7uF**) has broken off, I want to know what can I replace it with if I dont have specifically the same voltage and capacitance but the same dimensions 0805. The mobo is h61mxv v2.0 but the schematic is is for v1.0 still the circuit and caps are the same. if someone wants the schematic for further details I can give you a link.Also what does the "dummy" text signify?
[image: image of of broken of cap]

Comment: In the area of the PCB above ``C4`` it looks like the part of the surface on which traces are visible on the top layer has been damaged due to some sort of mechanical impact, which presumably broke ``C4`` off the motherboard. I.e. the PCB might have been damaged resulting in open circuit traces. Therefore, to repair the motherboard might require more than replacing ``C4``. Can you get a higher resolution picture of the damaged area above ``C4`` to help determine if the surface traces have been cut?

Comment: @ChesterGillon Its difficult to get a higher res image but I will try, but still thanks a lot because I didnt notice that at all.

Comment: @ChesterGillon got higher res images. it also seems that most of these traces do not connect to anything higher up. I dont know for sure though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any capacitor about that capacitance and rated for at least 6.3V.

If you don't have anything close, order a replacement. That's a few cents a part.

Comment: But wont it be dangerous if the voltage is higher than the original? It is very hard to find that specific capacitor for cheap where I live but I  have some caps at home.

Comment: The voltage rating is the maximum the capacitor can survive, so a higher value is after than a lower value. If you were thinking that the capacitor would charge itself up the rating, that doesn't happen because capacitors are not voltage sources. They experience whatever voltage is on the wire.